# android how to download images from server quickly

Tags: android

I have an application, where it downloads a no of images (no of images are not fixed) from server(internet).
at first i tried only one image  it took 2min to display.
Now i am trying to load 5 images so it takes 10 to 15 mins to display, which shouldnt be like this.
What can I do so that it take a small duration of time as a normal application takes.

Thank you

Comment: You should provide some of your code related to downloading because it is hard to answer your question

Comment: You should also indicate the details of the downloads too: network link details, image size, have you downloaded the images from elsewhere faster?

Comment: Use ImageLoader, it is the best solution till date As @Venky has mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AsyncTask - It will allow you to display images as and when they are downloaded. No need to wait for displaying till all the images are there !

Comment: I'll recommend you to go through this article : http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructs-part-3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lazy List that will cache the images in Cache memory and let you to load images very fast.

Check this Link [Lazy List sample](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-list-view-in.html).......

Comment: do you have any other way without using listview?

Comment: @Jyosna Where u have to set images? List or Grid or any thing else?

Comment: @Jyosna U can use this for any Widget. Just you need to customize it..Thats all..